# Hebrews 5:7; (Who) in the beginning of the verse refers to Melchisedec basically?

Tags: hebrews, melchizedek

Hebrews 5:5-10; DRB;

> 5 So Christ also did not glorify himself, that he might be made a high priest: but he that said unto him: Thou art my Son, this day have I begotten thee.
> 6 As he saith also in another place: Thou art a priest for ever, according to the order of **Melchisedech.
> 7 Who in the days of his flesh,** with a strong cry and tears, offering up prayers and supplications to him that was able to save him from death, **was heard for his reverence.**
> 8 And whereas indeed he was the Son of God, he learned obedience by the things which he suffered:
> 9 And being consummated, he became, to all that obey him, the cause of eternal salvation.
> 10 Called by God a high priest according to the order of Melchisedech.

Hebrews 5:6-7; KJV;

> 6 As he saith also in another place, Thou art a priest for ever after the order of **Melchisedec.
> 7 Who in the days of his flesh**, when he had offered up prayers and supplications with strong crying and tears unto him that was able to save him from death, and **was heard in that he feared;**

Hebrews 5:6-7; Young's Literal Translation;

> 6 as also in another [place] He saith, `Thou [art] a priest -- to the age, according to the order of **Melchisedek;'
> 7 who in the days of his flesh** both prayers and supplications unto Him who was able to save him from death -- with strong crying and tears -- having offered up, **and having been heard in respect to that which he feared,**

May verse 7 means Melchisedec? I.e: Melchisedec who (Melchisedec) in the days of his flesh...etc.

I read an issue which says that the Tithes may be made from Melchizedek to Ibrahim (Abraham) or vise versa, i.e: from Ibrahim (Abraham) to Melchizedek. The same idea is here, (Who) may means Jesus or Melchizedek.

N.B, the crucifixion (death) already happened to Jesus the Christ.

Answer (score 2):

There can be no question that the pronoun that begins Heb 5:7 is definitely "Jesus" as is made plain the in the subsequent verses as well:

> Heb 5:7-10 (BLB) - **He** in the days of **His** flesh, having offered up
> both prayers and supplications with loud crying and tears to the One
> being able to save **Him** from death, and having been heard because
> of reverent submission, though being **a Son**, **He** learned
> obedience from the things **He** suffered, and having been perfected,
> **He** became the author of eternal salvation to all those obeying **Him**, having been designated by God a **high priest** according to the order of Melchizedek.

In the Greek, this is one sentence and the entire sentence refers to Jesus as is made clear in (say) the BSB -

> Heb 5:7 ... - During the days of **Jesus’ earthly life**, He offered
> up prayers and petitions with loud cries and tears to the One who
> could save Him from death, and He was heard because of His reverence.
> ...

There is a similar result for most other such as NIV, NLT, ESV, Amplified Bible, CEV, etc.

Meyer correctly observes:

> Hebrews 5:7. **Ὅς** refers back to the last main idea, thus to ὁ
> Χριστός, Hebrews 5:5.

Cambridge is similar:

> 7. **Who** i.e. the Christ.
>
> **of his flesh** The word “flesh” is here used for His Humanity regarded on the side of its weakness and humiliation. Comp. Hebrews
> 2:14.

Comment: I read an issue which says that the Tithes may be made from Melchizedek to Ibrahim or vise versa, i.e: from Ibrahim to Melchizedek. The same idea is here, (Who) may means Jesus or Melchizedek.